# Retrofit - Pass URL values dynamically - GET method

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a URL for example :

https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/KMHDC8AEXAU084769?format=JSON

Here I want to change `KMHDC8AEXAU084769?format=JSON` this part dynamically

How to do it with Retrofit2.

I tried like:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @GET("{input}")
    Call<Result> getVin(@Path("input") String input, @Field("format") String format);
```

But `@FormUrlEncoded` is only supports for POST not for GET.

This is the way I am calling it:

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Result> call = apiService.getVin(vin, "JSON");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                Result result = response.body();

                Log.e("Result: ", "" + response.body());

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(result);

                responseTV.setText("" + json);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e("MainActivity", t.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Try later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
@GET("/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/{input}")
Call<Result> getVin(@Path("input") String input, @Query("format") String format);
```

@FormUrlEncoded and @Field annotations are for POST requests.

Current value of the parameter of @GET annotation may differ according to your baseUrl value you are using.

Answer (score 5):

This is described in the documentation....

> URL MANIPULATION
>
> A request URL can be updated dynamically using replacement blocks and
>   parameters on the method. A replacement block is an alphanumeric
>   string surrounded by { and }. A corresponding parameter must be
>   annotated with @Path using the same string.
>
> Query parameters can also be added.
>
> @GET("group/{id}/users") Call> groupList(@Path("id") int
>   groupId, @Query("sort") String sort);
>
> For complex query parameter
>   combinations a Map can be used.
>
> @GET("group/{id}/users") Call> groupList(@Path("id") int
>   groupId, @QueryMap Map options);

For your desired url structure this should work with something like this:

```
@GET("{id}")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int id, @Query("format") String format);
```

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: Of course you should adapt the url structure in the GET Annotation for your purposes